# Mistakenly using a moved value

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Having made the move to C++11, I am now systematically passing my strings by value in my constructors. But now, I realize that it makes it easier to introduce bugs when also using the value in the body of the constructor:

```
class A(std::string val):
  _val(std::move(val))
{
  std::cout << val << std::endl; // Bug!!!
}
```

What can I do to reduce the chances of getting it wrong?

Comment: "made the _move_ to C++11" very nice

Comment: "What can I do to reduce the chances of getting it wrong?" Not much. Leaving objects in valid but strange states is ludicrous, which is one reason that C++11's move semantics are silly.

Comment: Whats wrong with using _val inside the constructor's body?

Comment: @Thorsten: He forgot.

Comment: I was in the process of writing an answer, but it all boiled down to simply, "don't screw up in the first place & write unit tests."

Comment: @JohnDibling: Unit tests are unreliable for catching bugs through implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  So?

Comment: @JohnDibling: So your recommendation misses the mark.

Comment: @JohnDibling So Unit tests won't necessarily catch such things. Meaning, your boiled-down answer is not a good answer.

Comment: @ArneMertz:  It wasn't an answer at all.

Comment: C++ needs linear types!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  There is no silver bullet.  That doesn't mean we shouldn't test code.

Comment: I think it would be possible for compilers to catch most cases of this as a warning.  The optimizer could watch for any use of an object which might have been cast to an rvalue-reference (possibly by the inlined `std::move`) previously in the same function.  (Usual caveats about the compiler's limited ability to guess whether two glvalues might be the same object.)

Comment: @John: No, of course not. I never said that we shouldn't test code. I simply disagreed with your claim that your recommendation would have been a suitable answer to _this question_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  I made no such claim.  I would have posted it as an answer if I thought it was an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name arguments whose purpose is to be moved-from in some distinctive manner, at least within the implementation of the constructor

```
A::A(std::string val_moved_from):
 _val(std::move(val_moved_from))
{
  std::cout << val_moved_from << std::endl; // Bug, but obvious
}
```

then move from them as early as possible (in the construction list, say).

If you have such a long construction list you can miss two uses of `val_moved_from` in it, this doesn't help.

An alternative would be to write up a proposal to fix this problem.  Say, extend C++ so that the types or scopes of local variables can be changed by operations on them, so `std::safe_move(X)` both moves from `X` and marks `X` as an expired variable, no longer valid to use, for the remainder of its scope.  Working out what to do when a variable is half-expired (expired in one branch, but not in another) is an interesting question.

Because that is insane, we can instead attack it as a library problem.  To a certain limited extent, we can fake those kind of tricks (a variable whose type changes) at run time.  This is crude, but gives the idea:

```
template<typename T>
struct read_once : std::tr2::optional<T> {
  template<typename U, typename=typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U&&, T>::value>::type>
  read_once( U&& u ):std::tr2::optional<T>(std::forward<U>(u)) {}
  T move() && {
    Assert( *this );
    T retval = std::move(**this);
    *this = std::tr2::none_t;
    return retval;
  }
  // block operator*?
};
```

ie, write a linear type that can only be read from via `move`, and after that time reading `Assert`s or throws.

Then modify your constructor:

```
A::A( read_once<std::string> val ):
  _val( val.move() )
{
  std::cout << val << std::endl; // does not compile
  std::cout << val.move() << std::endl; // compiles, but asserts or throws
}
```

with forwarding constructors, you can expose a less ridiculous interface with no `read_once` types, then forward your constructors to your "safe" (possibly `private`) versions with `read_once<>` wrappers around the arguments.

If your tests cover all code paths, you'll get nice `Assert`s instead of just empty `std::string`s, even if you go and `move` more than once from your `read_once` variables.

Comment: But you have to remember to do all of this. If you can remember that, then you likely wouldn't have made the mistake in the first place.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure: but if you had a robust `read_once`, and followed the rule "always take 'by value to be copied' as `read_once`", you'd get `Assert` instead of empty data when you read it.  And the whistle does keep the tigers away, do you see any tigers?

Comment: And if you followed the rule "don't try to print the wrong variable" then it would all be moot

Answer (score 0):

"Having made the move to C++11, I am now systematically passing my strings by value in my constructors."

I'm sorry, I don't see why one would want to do this.  What improvement does this provide in relation to the traditional method? (which is basically bug proof).

`class A(const std::string & s):
  _val(s)
{
  std::cout << s << std::endl; // no Bug!!!
  std::cout << _val << std::endl; // no Bug either !!!
}`

Comment: To answer your question: yes, `std::move` is better than this because, well, less copies. What is more, your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Suppose you `s` is a 100,000 character string.  Your version always makes a copy of it, always, right here: `_val(s)`.  The above version will not make a copy of it if the caller does `std::move` into the constructor, or constructs `A` from a temporary `std::string`.  See [here](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) for a deeper discussion.  Note that having both a `std::string&& s` and `std::string const& s` constructor gives you 1 less move than taking `std::string s`, but doubles the amount of code you have to maintain.

Comment: In this case we're not making any copies at all as we're passing by reference. I'm very familiar with the cited discussion.  It addresses an situation where there are copies which is not the case here. The question posed is "What can I do to reduce the chances of getting it wrong?".  The answer is "Don't do that!".  Your not reducing any copies by doing this and you're introducing a bug.